# D-link DAP-1353 n2 not giving IP address

Tags: dhcp, wifi, d-link

I have a D-link DAP-1353 n2, I can connect to it fine, but I am not given an IP address. If I assign myself a static IP I can browse the network without any problems. Some other laptops are able to connect and get an IP without any problems.

It seems to be about 50/50 of users that can and can't connect and there is no obvious connection between them. What can I check that might help?

Comment: So statics work but DHCP doesn't? or is it more intermittant? Have you checked that your scope is big enough? rebooted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out the the router had a date set of something in 1970, I set the date correctly and pointed it at a time server and it now serves the IP addresses as it should.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using?
Maybe the driver is too old for your Laptop WLAN Card/Stick.

Maybe you can try in the command shell:

ipconfig /renew

Checked for Known Issues on D-Link homepage?

Comment: I'm using vista, some other users are on XP and one is using the HTC Hero phone.